# update query not executing in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

can you help me solve this? my update query in my else statement is not excuting but it's working in the if statement. Here's the code.

```
        while($qtytoAdd > 0) {
    $remBalance = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `est_qty` - `qty_rec` as balance FROM `estimates` WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` ORDER BY `item_id` ASC'), 0);
    $balid = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `est_id` FROM `estimates` WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` ORDER BY `item_id` ASC'), 0);
    $currRec = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `qty_rec` FROM `estimates` WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty`'), 0);
    $currid = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT `req_id` FROM `requestdetails` JOIN `request` USING(`req_id`) WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `req_qty` <> `current_rec_qty` ORDER BY `req_id` ASC'), 0);

        if(($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
            mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = `qty_rec` + "'.$qtytoAdd.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
                $qtytoAdd = 0;
        mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_onhand` = `qty_rec` - `qty_rel` WHERE `proj_id` = '.$proj_id.' AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` AND `mat_id` = '.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).' AND `est_id` = '.$balid.'');
            } else {
                mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = "'.$remBalance.'" + "'.$currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
                $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance;
        mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_onhand` = `qty_rec` - `qty_rel` WHERE `proj_id` = '.$proj_id.' AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` AND `mat_id` = '.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).' AND `est_id` = '.$balid.'');
            }
        }
```

I don't really know what the problem is. The query that I'm talking about is this one:

```
mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_onhand` = `qty_rec` - `qty_rel` WHERE `proj_id` = '.$proj_id.' AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` AND `mat_id` = '.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).' AND `est_id` = '.$balid.'');
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: okay sir.Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I see you're using `$proj_id` as a string. Is that the correct data type?

Comment: No sir, that's a primary key. But I think that will work fine in queries.

Answer (score 0):

if its not working inside else statement, why dont u try echoing the query and then copy that query and paste it into query analyser or phpmyadmin and check there whether it runs or not. something like this:

```
  else {
      $query="enter your query here";
      echo $query;
      mysql_query($query);
  }
```

After printing the query in the browser you would know what query is being run and check whether it is correct or not. some debugging skill is required

Comment: Is there anything to echo for an UPDATE query? I think that will show me a blank page?

Comment: yes i m saying you could echo this line $query='UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_onhand` = `qty_rec` - `qty_rel` WHERE `proj_id` = '.$proj_id.' AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` AND `mat_id` = '.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).' AND `est_id` = '.$balid.''';  on running it on browser, you would get the query that mysql runs. something like update test set data=1 where id=5. then you could copy this query and try running it in phpmyadmin to check whether the query runs or not else phpmyadmin throws error which u could debug

Comment: have u checked whether else statement is ever called ? what error message do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      else {
            mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_rec` = "'.$remBalance + $currRec.'" WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');

    mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_onhand` = `qty_rec` - `qty_rel` WHERE `proj_id` = '.$proj_id.' AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` AND `mat_id` = '.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).' AND `est_id` = '.$balid.'');
        }
        $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance;
    }
```

EDIT.

try replace your query by this

```
 mysql_query('UPDATE `estimates` SET `qty_onhand` = `qty_rec` - `qty_rel` WHERE `proj_id` = "'.$proj_id.'" AND `qty_rec` <> `est_qty` AND `mat_id` = "'.mat_id_from_mat_desc($materials).'" AND `est_id` = "'.$balid.'"');
```

Comment: Still the same result sir.

Comment: your query is good , verfiy if you have the problem somewhere

Comment: i think that's the only part I'm having trouble.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem.Using function in your else loop would work

```
else
{
    $update_function=update_function($ud_id,$subject,$to_user,$from_user);
    [//pass your variables instead of $ud_id,$subject,$to_user,$from_user]
}

function update_function($ud_id,$subject,$to_user,$from_user)
{               
    //place your query over here    
    $query=mysql_query("UPDATE `email_configuration` SET `subject`='$subject',`to_user`='$to_user',`from_user`='$from_user' WHERE id='$ud_id'");    
    echo "Record Updated";                              
}
```